# Will equivalence between $\|\cdot\|_1, \|\cdot\|_2$ preserver the order between $\|x\|_i, \|y\|_i (i = 1, 2)$

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

$\hspace{0.44cm}$In a infinitely dimensional Banach space $X$, given two linearly independent elements $x, y$ in the closed unit ball of $X$ and two positive real numbers $r_1, r_2 > 0$ such that $r_1+r_2 = 1$, are there any sufficient conditions on $x, y$ or the entire $X$, or $r$, which can imply:

$$
\|r_1x+r_2y\| \geq r\|x+y\|\,\forall\,r \leq \min(r_1, r_2)
$$

$\hspace{0.44cm}$As the first comment mentioned, in $\operatorname{Span}(x, y)$, define $\|ax+by\|_m = \max(\vert\,a\,\vert, \vert\,b\,\vert)$ and then in $\operatorname{Span}(x, y), \|\cdot\|, \|\cdot\|_m$ will be equivalent and hence for any $0 < r \leq \max(r_1, r_2)$ we will have $\|r_1x+r_2y\|_m \geq r\|x+y\|_m$ but how to compare $\|r_1x+r_2y\|$ and $r\|x+y\|$? When $x, y$ are fixed, we can find $0 < a < b$ such that $a\|r_1x+r_2y\|_m \leq \|r_1x+r_2y\| \leq b\|r_1x+r_2y\|_m\,\forall\,r_1, r_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ but how to know the range of $a, b$?

Given $r_2 > r_1 > 0, r_1+r_2 = 1$, an infinitely dimensional Banach space $X$ and $x, y$ in the closed unit ball:

1. Is there a suffcient condition on $x, y$ or $X$ such that:
   $$
   \|r_1x+r_2y\|\geq r\|x+y\|\,\forall\,r \leq r_1
   $$

Can we find the $\sup$ of $r > 0$ such that the statement above holds?

2. Is there a sufficient condition on $x, y$ or $X$ such that:
   $$
   \|r_1x+r_2y\|\geq r\|x+y\|\,\forall\,r \in (r_1, r_2)
   $$

Can we find $\sup$ or $\inf$ for this $r$?

3. Is there a sufficient condition on $x, y$ or $X$ or $r_1, r_2$ such that:
   $$
   \|r_1x+r_2y\|\geq r\|x+y\|\,\forall\,r \geq r_2
   $$

Again I would like to know the $\sup$ of $r$ in this case. Could one of $\sup$ or $\inf$ be $r_2$?

Comment: Just a comment: since what you are asking depends only on $x,y$ which are just two vectors, the problem is kind of independent of $X$, in the sense that you can pass to the 2-dimensional subspace spanned by $x,y$. In other words, studying the problem for $X$=2 dimensional and the norm being any possible norm on a 2-dimensional space suffices.

Comment: I got what you mean. To prove the first two questions I will consider this norm: $\|ax+by\|_m = max(\vert\,a\,\vert, \vert\,b\,\vert)$ for $x, y$ and $\|\cdot\|_m$ will be equivalent to the given $\|\cdot\|$. Then in the first two questions will have $\|r_1x+r_2y\|_m \geq r\|x+y\|_m$ but how to show $\|r_1x+r_2y\| \geq r\|x+y\|$?. I am not sure in general if knowing $\|\cdot\|_1\sim\|\cdot\|_2$ we will have $\|a\|_1\geq\|b\|_1\,\implies\,\|a\|_2 \geq \|b\|_2$.

Comment: I'm not sure how to continue from here; at first sight this seems difficult to me, I can't think of anything:)

Comment: No worry. Any further inputs will be appreciated :)

Comment: This question seems to vague to me. What kind of conditions are you looking for? There is no non-trivial normed space where this inequality holds for all $x,y,r_1,r_2$ simply because one can always find counterexample like $y=-2x$, $r_1=2$, $r_2=1$. On the other hand it is true if $x$ and $y$ lie on the same ray or $X$ is an inner product space and $x\perp y$.

Comment: @MaoWao I will edit the question soon and only consider, in a Banach space when will $\|\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y\| \geq r\|x+y\|$ if $\lambda \in (0, 1)$ and $x, y$ are linearly independent elements in a Banach space. You example in a inner product space works indeed.